# QueryDSL 5.0.0 y SpringBoot 3. Error en QClasses

Tags: java, spring, maven, querydsl

He estado trajando todo el rato con QueryDSL 5 y SpringBoot 3 correctamente.
Cambié algo del `pom.xml` que no me acuerdo y me ha dejado de funcionar todas las `QClasses`:

> Generated cannot be resolved to a type.

y me hace un

```
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;
```

cosa que no debería porque estoy con `jakarta`.

Si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradecería!!!

Comment: Tal vez ayudaría si agregas tu pom